# How To Check If A Visual Studio Extension Is Safe

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to examine a Visual Studio Extension before installing to see if it is safe?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an in-built way to check if an extension is non-malicious. However if this is something you are worried about then there are quite a few extensions built off of proven open-source packages.

You can also download the extension and then extract the .VSIX file to look at some of the source code for the extension.

Bearing in mind that the main attack vector would be a malicious or compromised extension dev (as all extensions are signed). Open-source, well-proven packages from reputable devs are the way to go. This is normally a requirement in secure development environments.

Comment: Thank you Tom.  
I might be overly cautious.  The extension I'm considering is on marketplace.visualstudio.com.  Much of the information for the extension is in Chinese.  I know there has been a lot of caution when using Chinese products.
Should I "assume" that if it is on a Microsoft site that it is safe?

Comment: No, don't assume that all extensions are safe, they are third-party extensions hosted on Microsoft servers. Even if Microsoft do screen the third party code they host, malicious code can always get through.